# Byte between two element

Tags: c++, arrays, element

My teacher ask me a question and he said the answer is 48 bytes

[image]

please explain to me.

Comment: Print `p1` and `p2` and look at the values.

Comment: `sizeof(double)` is 8 bytes.

Comment: i thing it is 47

Comment: @ĐăngKhôi - I know I was about to say the same thing (or suggest 40)! (ಠ⌣ಠ)  "between" is such an ambiguous word.

Comment: @ĐăngKhôi Let's consider another array containing char. How many bytes would you say there are between m_char[0] and m_char[1]?

Comment: Can you please stop posting pictures here!

Comment: It's a trick question: p1 and p2 are right next to each other on the stack, so there are zero bytes between them. Tell your teacher to provide less ambiguous questions.

Comment: The real question here is to interpret your teacher's language, which is not on topic.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the *between* here means how many bytes far apart the two pointers point to.

Given:

```
p1 = m;     // 0th index, 1st element
p2 = &m[6]; // 6th index, 7th element
            // 7 - 1 = 6 elements (between)
```

So, `p1` and `p2` are 6 elements of `double` type far apart.

`sizeof(double)` on that architecture should be 8 bytes.

Hence,

```
6 elements x sizeof(double) = 6 x 8 = 48 bytes
```

Programmatically, it would be:

```
auto bytes = (p2 - p1) * sizeof(double);
```

Here's an example ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/m_kq7y)):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double m[100];
    double *p1, *p2;

    p1 = m;         // 0th index, 1st element
    p2 = &m[6];     // 6th index, 7th element

    const auto bytes = (p2 - p1) * sizeof(double);
    std::cout << "Bytes: " << bytes;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Bytes: 48
```

---

[std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) may also be used for calculating distance:

```
auto bytes = std::distance( p1, p2 );
```